# EmberJs: How to get collapsed in side-nav on route change

Tags: ember.js, nav

Suppose I have a side-nav with second-level, i.e, 'groups' has sub-nav 'group1', 'group2' etc. Currently when I navigate to groups/gropui by clicking on groupi from side-nav it is properly collapsed in. But if I reload the page then it is collapsed not opened. How can I ensure that even the page refresh remains it collapsed in that is opened?

Comment: You can't keep the state between refreshes. If you refresh the page, with any client framework, it's as if you're landing on the page for the first time. To do what you are saying, you'd have to store (cookie, localStorage, something like that) the state of your menu and check each time the app/page loads for that stored state and apply it to your component.

Comment: Have you considered to use query params? http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/query-params/

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the state of group that need to be open. This can be done if you store data somewhere about it.

I suggest using the Local Storage of browser. [This](https://github.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter) is a good Ember CLI plugin which will provide support for Local Storage.